# How to create a lighting that illuminates all the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a scene in editor and it looks good there. I imported this model to Unity but it looks bad because of I don't know how to create a good light for this scene. Directional light is a bad choice in this case because I get a very light scene but if to change slider - very dark. So I need the Unity light to be the same as in editor. So I need your help how to do it. Thanks in advance.

[**Object in editor**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72oCc.png)

[**Object in Unity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1aZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use ambient lighting. Ambient Lighting is a form of a global light source. Here is a link to a page on it https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/ambient-lighting